# UITextView data change swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

How can you detect a change of data in a `UITextView` with `Swift`? The following code does not do any detection.

I am declaring the `UITextView` :

```
@IBOutlet weak var bodyText: UITextView!

optional func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView!) {
    println(bodyText.text)
}
```

Thanks
Scott

Comment: This UITextView placeholder solution provides a working example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652227/text-view-placeholder-swift/28271069#28271069

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You need to set UITextView [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextViewDelegate) and implement [textViewDidChange:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewDidChange:) method in it. Unfortunately, I do not know if swift documentation is available online.  All the links go to the objective-c documentation.

The code will look like this: (**updated for SWIFT 4.2**)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate { //If your class is not conforms to the UITextViewDelegate protocol you will not be able to set it as delegate to UITextView

    @IBOutlet weak var bodyText: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        bodyText.delegate = self //Without setting the delegate you won't be able to track UITextView events
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) { //Handle the text changes here
        print(textView.text); //the textView parameter is the textView where text was changed
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this method only get called when the text value changes, or does it also respond to changes in the attributed text property (bold/italics/etc)?

Comment: Have not tested. But it seems the method will respond any changes in the text

Answer (score 6):

For my case, I wanted the implementation to be independent from a UIViewController, so i dont need to assign a delegate just for text changes. Or even maybe there is some kind of validation on the UITextView, and you wanna contain it per field instead of a delegate managing a lot of complicated logic.

It requires to subclass UITextView, but its very much worth it imo:

```
class TextView: UITextView {

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero, textContainer: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textDidChangeNotification), name: UITextView.textDidChangeNotification , object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func textDidChangeNotification(_ notif: Notification) {
        guard self == notif.object as? UITextView else {
            return
        }
        textDidChange()
    }

    func textDidChange() {
        // the text in the textview just changed, below goes the code for whatever you need to do given this event

        // or you can just set the textDidChangeHandler closure to execute every time the text changes, useful if you want to keep logic out of the class
        textDidChangeHandler?()
    }

    var textDidChangeHandler: (()->Void)?

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Set `delegate` of `UITextView`.Refer [UITextViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewDidChange:)

Write this in `viewDidLoad`

```
bodyText!.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 4:

```html
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
  // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 4.2, you can add `UITextViewTextDidChange`, `UITextViewTextDidBeginEditing` & `UITextViewTextDidEndEditing` notification observers to a UITextView like this:

```
let nc = NotificationCenter.default
nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textViewDidChange), name: NSNotification.Name.UITextViewTextDidChange , object: nil)
nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textViewDidBeginEditing), name: NSNotification.Name.UITextViewTextDidBeginEditing , object: nil)
nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textViewDidEndEditing), name: NSNotification.Name.UITextViewTextDidEndEditing , object: nil)
```

And the observers look like this:

```
@objc func textViewDidChange(_ notif: Notification) {
    guard notif.object is UITextView else { return }
    // Do something
}

@objc func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ notif: Notification) {
    guard notif.object is UITextView else { return }
    // Do something
}

@objc func textViewDidEndEditing(_ notif: Notification) {
    guard notif.object is UITextView else { return }
    // Do something
}
```

For Swift5, the format of the 'name' values are `UITextView.textDidChangeNotification`.

Answer (score 0):

### When subclassing UITextView:

```
import UIKit
class SelfAwareTextView: UITextView {
    
    func setup() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
         selector: #selector(change),
         name: UITextView.textDidChangeNotification,
         object: self)
    }
    
    @objc func change(_ notif: Notification) {
        print("the user edited the text. It's now: " + text)
    }
}
```

In add observor, the `object:` is the sending object.

Somewhat confusingly, you set that to `self` since, in fact, we simply want notifications from ourself; we don't care about other text views.

Regarding `setup`, recall that (in general) when subclassing a UITextView, you want to do setup in `awakeFromNib` rather than init, etc, since, among other issues you then catch any IBInspectable values.