# How to clear UITextView upon editing?

Tags: swift, uitextview

I currently have the following code:

```
class NewPostController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var MessageField: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    MessageField.text = "What's on your mind?"
    MessageField.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(MessageField: UITextView) {
    if MessageField.textColor == UIColor.lightGrayColor() {
        MessageField.text = ""
        MessageField.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
}
```

However, whenever I edit `MessageField`, the code within `textViewDidBeginEditing` doesn't run. I suspect this is because of an invalid way of referencing `MessageField` within the function, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652227/text-view-placeholder-swift

Comment: I don't know swift, but I suppose you must delegate your text view to execute textViewDidVeginEditing. You must call [MessageField setDelegate:self] (equivalent in swift syntax) and you must add <UITextViewDelegate>

Comment: @AdrianB, the specifics of the code don't change the fact that I can write in `println("Hi")` within `textViewDidBeginEditing`, but it still doesn't run.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Looks like you're not setting your `UITextView`'s `delegate`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTextView.delegate = self
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    myTextView.text = String()
}
```

[**UITextViewDelegate Protocol Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html)

Comment: func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    textView.text = ""
}   **this also works.**

Answer (score 1):

And to make @DanielStorm's answer work in Swift 3:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    myTextView.text = ""
}
```

Comment: Question isn't how to convert to Swift 3. And also, your instance variable is not defined, so is confusing.

Comment: Well at least format it decently, I mean it's only 3 lines.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers already given, I'd probably take the approach of storing whether it's been cleared initially as an instance variable on your class. In most use cases, the user would expect it to be cleared only when they begin editing the first time (to get rid of any placeholder text):

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if !self.textViewClearedOnInitialEdit {
        self.textView.text = ""
        self.textViewClearedOnInitialEdit = true
    }
}
```