# init(colorLiteralRed:,green:,blue:,alpha:) deprecated in Swift 4

Tags: uicolor, swift4

```
let startingColorOfGradient = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 255/255, green: 
255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
let endingColorOFGradient = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 251/255, green: 
247/255, blue: 234/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
```

**Error:**

> 'init(colorLiteralRed:green:blue:alpha:)' was obsoleted in Swift 4.0 (Swift._ExpressibleByColorLiteral)

How do I use gradient color if `init(colorLiteralRed:,green:,blue:,alpha:)` is deprecated in Swift 4?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`init(colorLiteralRed:green:blue:alpha:)` is intended to be used with Color Literals which are managed by development tools.

Why don't you use normal `init(red:green:blue:alpha:)`?

```
let startingColorOfGradient = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green:
    255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
let endingColorOFGradient = UIColor(red: 251.0/255.0, green:
    247.0/255.0, blue: 234.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
```

(Writing like `234.0/255.0` is not mandatory, in the context as above in Swift. But it prevents Swift compiler to interpret `234/255` as an integer division in some other contexts.)

Comment: There are two new methods in UIColor that accepts integer values from 0 to 255. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58124535/2631081

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use below method of UIColor class to instantiate color from Red, Green, Blue, Alpha.

Note: Red, Green, Blue, and Alpha have a value ranging from 0 to 1.

```
let colorStart = UIColor(red:0.1 , green: 0.2, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)
let colorEnd = UIColor(red:0.21 , green: 0.32, blue: 0.15, alpha: 1.0)

func createGradientLayer() {
     gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
     gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
     gradientLayer.colors = [colorStart.CGColor, colorEnd.CGColor]
     self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
}
```

To create gradient layer you can take reference from

https://www.appcoda.com/cagradientlayer/

Answer (score 2):

Another way : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621925-init

> ***init(displayP3Red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)***
>
> Initializes and returns a color object using the specified opacity and RGB component values in the Display P3 color space.

you can use `displayP3Red` instead of `colorLiteralRed`

```
let startingColorOfGradient = UIColor(displayP3Red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
let endingColorOFGradient = UIColor(displayP3Red: 251/255, green: 247/255, blue: 234/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
UIColor(red: CGFloat(255.0), green: CGFloat(255.0), blue: CGFloat(255.0), alpha: CGFloat(255.0))
```