# Setting font for UITextfield place holder in swift

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uitextfield, placeholder

I used the following code for setting different font for UITextfield's text(16) and placeholder(9),

```
m_searchTextField.font = UIFont .systemFontOfSize(16)
let font = UIFont .systemFontOfSize(9)
let attributes = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGrayColor(),
        NSFontAttributeName : font]

 m_searchTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Search String be in meddle left",
        attributes:attributes)
```

Font size is set correctly, but the placeholder text sets somewhat upper in the textfield.

[image]

How can I fix this issue? Any Suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652227/text-view-placeholder-swift/28271069#28271069

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue programmatically, since I could not find any other way to fix it.

Code below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    var placeholder : UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        placeholder = UILabel(frame: CGRect( x: 0, y: 0, width: textField.bounds.width, height: textField.bounds.height))
        placeholder.text = "Search String be in meddle left"
        placeholder.font = UIFont.italicSystemFontOfSize(9)
        placeholder.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        placeholder.hidden = !textField.text!.isEmpty
        placeholder.textAlignment = .Center
        textField.addSubview(placeholder)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func textField_EditingChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
        placeholder.hidden = !textField.text!.isEmpty
    }
}
```