# Swift UITextView Event Listener

Tags: swift

My question is how would I set an event listener to listen if the user has typed a character into a UITextView?

I know I can use `textview.hasText()` to check if it has text but I need to listen for a character typed even if there is already text in the UITextView.

Comment: This `UITextView `placeholder answer provides a simple functional example of how to use a `UITextViewDelegate` ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652227/text-view-placeholder-swift/28271069#28271069

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at [UITextViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/).

For example if you have

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!;
```

Do conform to the UITextViewDelegate protocol in your view controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

// stuff
}
```

In your viewDidLoad method add

```
textView.delegate = self;
```

Then depending on what you want to listen for, implement the methods from UITextViewDelegate you need.

For example, if you want to listen for when the text view changed implement:

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    // your code here.
    print(textView.text);
}
```

**Edit:** To reflect on the comment do implement this method:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

}
```

From Apple's documentation:

> Tells the delegate that the text or attributes in the specified text
>   view were changed by the user.

Comment: This is close but I don't think it's quite right for what I need to accomplish. I don't want to listen for `textViewDidEndEditing()` because that would imply that they keyboard closed and editing stopped when I need to listen while editing is in process and the keyboard open.

Comment: I looked around on Apple's documentation and found `textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)`. This may be what I'm looking for.