# Multi-line user input in iOS: UITextField vs UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview, multiline

I need to show users a multi-line text input "box" with a height greater than the standard height of a `UITextField`. What the best or most correct approach should be?:

1. Using a `UITextField` and change its height in code or by applying a certain height constraint.
2. Using an editable `UITextView`. This is multi-line but it has no placeholder by default, I guess I should implement that feature in code.

Comment: you should go with option 2 , because with changing height of textfield never shows it in two line

Comment: Check out this simple library: https://github.com/rlaguilar/MultilineTextField

Answer (score 96):

`UITextField` is specifically one line only.

Use `UITextView` instead for multiline text.

To implement the placeholder in UITextView use this logic/code.

First set the UITextView to contain the placeholder text and set it to a light gray color to mimic the look of a UITextField's placeholder text. Either do so in the `viewDidLoad` or upon the text view's creation.

**For Swift**

```
textView.text = "Placeholder"
textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
```

**For Objective-C**

```
textView.text = @"Placeholder";
textView.textColor =[UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

Then when the user begins to edit the text view, if the text view contains a placeholder (i.e. if its text color is light gray) clear the placeholder text and set the text color to black in order to accommodate the user's entry.

**For Swift**

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGrayColor() {
        textView.text = nil
        textView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
}
```

**For Objective-C**

```
- (BOOL) textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (textView.textColor == [UIColor lightGrayColor]) {
        textView.text = @"";
        textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Then when the user finishes editing the text view and it's resigned as the first responder, if the text view is empty, reset its placeholder by re-adding the placeholder text and setting its color to light gray.

**For Swift**

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.isEmpty {
        textView.text = "Placeholder"
        textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    }
}
```

**For Objective-C**

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        textView.text = @"Placeholder";
        textView.textColor =[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
}
```

Also do add `UITextViewDelegate` in the view controller.

Comment: none of functions didn't call. when i used UITextViewDelegate, it worked perfectly

Comment: In Swift it's important to note that the delegate functions can't be private (it will compile but these will not be called)

Comment: It didn't worked for me until I added in the viewDidLoad()-Method the following code:
`textView.delegate = self`
(assigning the textViews delegate to self)

Comment: I can't believe a dumb placeholder on a multi-line text input needs so much code. Gotta love android

Answer (score 12):

Go with option two, the height of the textField cannot be changed and it doesn't display the second line...

### PLACEHOLDER LOGIC:

```
textView.text = "Placeholder"
textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGrayColor() {
        textView.text = nil
        textView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
}
func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.isEmpty {
        textView.text = "Placeholder"
        textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    }
}
```

From [Text View Placeholder Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652227/text-view-placeholder-swift).

Answer (score 6):

**For Swift 3**

`UITextView` doesn't inherently have a placeholder property so you'd have to create and manipulate one programmatically using `UITextViewDelegate` methods.

(Note: Add `UITextViewDelegate` to the class and set `textView.delegate = self`.)

First set the `UITextView` to contain the placeholder text and set it to a light gray color to mimic the look of a `UITextField`'s placeholder text. Either do so in the `viewDidLoad` or upon the text view's creation.

```
textView.text = "Placeholder"
textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
```

Then when the user begins to edit the text view, if the text view contains a placeholder (i.e. if its text color is light gray) clear the placeholder text and set the text color to black in order to accommodate the user's entry.

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray {
        textView.text = nil
        textView.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
```

Then when the user finishes editing the text view and it's resigned as the first responder, if the text view is empty, reset its placeholder by re-adding the placeholder text and setting its color to light gray.

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.isEmpty {
        textView.text = "Placeholder"
        textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You can't do multiline text using `UITextField`, You should go with `UITextView` and implement the placeholder logic.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go with `UITextView`. In case you want to set placeholder text, `UITextView+Placeholder` allows to set it easily. You can install it using

```
pod 'UITextView+Placeholder', '~> 1.2'
```

in your pod file.
Now you can import header

```
#import <UITextView+Placeholder/UITextView+Placeholder.h>
```

which helps to set placeholder easily.

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
textView.placeholder = @"How are you?";
textView.placeholderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; // optional
textView.attributedPlaceholder = ... // NSAttributedString (optional)
```