# Hide placeholder Programatically using swift 3x

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uitextfield, placeholder

How to hide the placeholder of `TextField` programmatically using Swift 3x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not hide the `placeholder` of `UITextField`, but you can set it to empty String.

```
self.textField.placeholder = ""
```

Now `textField` doesn't show any `placeholder` later on if you want to show the `placeholder` simply set it with String that you want.

```
self.textField.placeholder = "Enter name"
```

Comment: If you're using `UITextView` the solution becomes quite different.  Here are a couple of solutions. [Floating Placeholder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28271069/2079103) and [Fake Native Placeholders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652227/text-view-placeholder-swift/41081244#41081244)

Comment: @clearlight Thanks for link, but OP already specify he want this functionality for `UITextField` not for `UITextView`.

Comment: But visitors to the question may be interested in a related solution. Remember it's just a comment, not posted as an answer.

Comment: @clearlight I know and that's why I have written *Thanks for link*