# Swift UITextView placeholder not hiding after click enabled

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario, I am trying to create `UITextView` with a custom Placeholder by using below code, But whenever I clicked into UITextview my `Placeholder` not hide. How to fix this?

My Code Below

In `ViewDidLoad`

```
  myTextview.delegate = self

  self.myTextview.text = "Enter Comments"
            self.myTextview.textColor = UIColor .lightGray
```

Added below two `UITextView` Delegates

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if myTextview.textColor == UIColor.lightGray {
            myTextview.text = nil
            myTextview.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if myTextview.text.isEmpty {
            myTextview.text = "Enter Comments"
            myTextview.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `textViewDidBeginEditing` being called? Did you set the `delegate`?

Comment: @rmaddy yes I did it even not working

Comment: @rmaddy **textViewDidBeginEditing** its not calling

Comment: Then the text view's delegate is not set.

Comment: `myTextView.delegate` and `self.myTextView.delegate` are not the same thing.

Comment: did u set myTextview.delegate = self in viewdidload
Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652227/text-view-uitextview-placeholder-swift

Comment: Your code looks fine, and is working at my end. Did you set `UITextViewDelegate` with class?

Comment: @manishsharma93 Yes I added UITextViewDelegate. for me also its working but whenever I click the textview its not deleting

Answer (score 1):

Hello i have same issue and i got solution like below i hope its work for you

Below is my code

**CODE**

```
var placeholderLabel : UILabel!
```

PUT This Code inside your `viewDidLoad()`

```
yourTextView.delegate = self
placeholderLabel = UILabel()
placeholderLabel.text = "Your Place Holder Text"
placeholderLabel.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: (yourTextView.font?.pointSize)!)
placeholderLabel.sizeToFit()
yourTextView.addSubview(placeholderLabel)
placeholderLabel1.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 5, y: (yourTextView.font?.pointSize)! / 2)
placeholderLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
placeholderLabel.isHidden = !yourTextView.text.isEmpty
```

then inside your `textViewDidChange` write below code

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        placeholderLabel.isHidden = !yourTextView.text.isEmpty
}
```

please try with this and tell me your problem is solved or not

Answer (score 0):

Working below code for `UITextView` Placeholder.

The actual question and Its solution.

Whenever user click the `UITextView` the placeholder should visible also If user enter anything text inside UITextView, Then the placeholder should hide and allow to show a user typing text. But the problem is not hiding `placeholder` whenever user enable to type.

It should work like a `TextField` Placeholder. Below code helping me to fix my issue.

```
import UIKit

class PlaceholderTextView: UITextView {

    @IBInspectable var placeholderColor: UIColor = UIColor.lightGray
    @IBInspectable var placeholderText: String = ""

    override var font: UIFont? {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override var contentInset: UIEdgeInsets {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override var textAlignment: NSTextAlignment {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override var attributedText: NSAttributedString? {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setUp()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
    }

    private func setUp() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.textChanged(notification:)),
                                               name: Notification.Name("UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification"),
                                               object: nil)
    }

    @objc func textChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    func placeholderRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var x = contentInset.left + 4.0
        var y = contentInset.top  + 9.0
        let w = frame.size.width - contentInset.left - contentInset.right - 16.0
        let h = frame.size.height - contentInset.top - contentInset.bottom - 16.0

        if let style = self.typingAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle] as? NSParagraphStyle {
            x += style.headIndent
            y += style.firstLineHeadIndent
        }
        return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let text = self.text,
            let font = self.font else {
                return
        }

        let fontKey = NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.font.rawValue)
        let colorKey = NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue)
        let paragraphKey = NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle.rawValue)
        if text.isEmpty && !placeholderText.isEmpty {
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.alignment = textAlignment
            let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
                fontKey: font,
                colorKey: placeholderColor,
                paragraphKey: paragraphStyle]

            placeholderText.draw(in: placeholderRectForBounds(bounds: bounds), withAttributes: attributes)
        }
        super.draw(rect)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your updated answer doesn't explain what was wrong with the code in your question.

Comment: @rmaddy In my question which I mentioned that code not hiding Placeholder after typing text into UITextView. I don't know what else I need to explain for you buddy. :)

Comment: Your answer should explain *why* your original code wasn't working.

Answer (score -7):

Change your code to

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if myTextview.text == "Enter Comments" {
        myTextview.text = ""
        myTextview.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if myTextview.text == "" {
        myTextview.text = "Enter Comments"
        myTextview.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP has made it clear that `textViewDidBeginEditing` isn't being called. So changing what it does doesn't fix anything.

Comment: @rmaddy We cannot check equality of color. He is trying to check the color in the if condition.

Comment: But the method isn't be called so the `if` statement is irrelevant at this point.

Comment: I am trying to explain the logic of code he is using in the delegate method.

Comment: You are missing the point. `textViewDidBeginEditing` is not being called. The code inside it currently irrelevant. Your answer makes no attempt to solve the problem of the delegate method not being called at all.

Comment: in his question, he is saying that the placeholder is not hiding. Not the method is not getting invoked.

Comment: You need to read the comments below the question where the OP stated that it's not being called.

Comment: I posted my answer before the comments added in his question.

Comment: And after posting my answer only he updated his question.

Comment: And you need to update your answer based on the new information. That's a risk you take when you post an answer too quickly without all of the relevant information.

Comment: I post the answer based on the codes he mention in the question.