# Hide Button if TextFields are Empty Equation Not Working

Tags: swift

I have 2 different textfields and I want to hide the button if these textfields are empty, and make this button visible when it is filled. I made an equation like below. The button does not appear on the first boot, but it does not appear when I fill in the data. Where is wrong?

```
var secilenLatitude = Double()
var secilenLongitude = Double()

@IBOutlet weak var isimTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var notTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var lokasyonuKaydet: UIButton!

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    mapView.delegate = self
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    
    let gestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(konumSec(gestureRecognizer:)))
    mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    
    let keyboardGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(klavyeyiKapat))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(keyboardGR)
    
    if isimTextField.text!.isEmpty == true && notTextField.text!.isEmpty == true {
        lokasyonuKaydet.isHidden = true
    } else {
        lokasyonuKaydet.isHidden = false
    }
    
    
}

@objc func klavyeyiKapat() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

@objc func konumSec(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
        let dokunulanNokta = gestureRecognizer.location(in: mapView)
        let dokunulanKoordinat = mapView.convert(dokunulanNokta, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = dokunulanKoordinat
        annotation.title = isimTextField.text
        annotation.subtitle = notTextField.text
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
    
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: locations[0].coordinate.latitude, longitude: locations[0].coordinate.longitude)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan.init(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, span: span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

My Storyboard:
[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etDWS.png)

Comment: When this condition evaluated? Please share more code

Comment: Create a [mre]. We don't even know the UI framework you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I updated my codes again and added an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a new delegate `UITextFieldDelegate`

I made definitions in viewDidLoad

```
isimTextField.delegate = self
notTextField.delegate = self
```

I created a new function

```
 func updateButtonVisibility() {
    if isimTextField.text!.isEmpty == true && notTextField.text!.isEmpty == true {
        lokasyonuKaydet.isHidden = true
      } else {
        lokasyonuKaydet.isHidden = false
      }
  }
```

Add delegate method:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    updateButtonVisibility()
    return true
}
```

Again `viewDidLoad`:

```
updateButtonVisibility()
```

and after these processes it started working. Please correct me if i have mistakes

Comment: `didBeginEditing` is wrong method for check. At this point text value hasn't changed yet. `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` would be better place, since it called on every text changed

Comment: I understand what you mean but I have no idea how to implement this, I'm a beginner yet. Can you make a small adaptation with my code for me to see?

Comment: I updated your answer

Comment: Thank you, but when I fill the first textfield, the button becomes active, and when I delete the data, the button remains. I guess I'd better try this when I'm much more pro :)

Answer (score 0):

Code in `viewDidLoad` executed only once. Instead you need to check for text every time text have been changed.

To achieve this you can add view controller as `UITextField` delegate as described in [UITextView data change swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064465/uitextview-data-change-swift)

Quick and dirty solution would be:

```swift
@objc func klavyeyiKapat() {
    view.endEditing(true)
    if isimTextField.text!.isEmpty == true && notTextField.text!.isEmpty == true {
        lokasyonuKaydet.isHidden = true
    } else {
        lokasyonuKaydet.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem by making a few changes thanks to your message. I am sharing my solution, if there is an error, I would be happy if you correct it.